# Why does PHP seem to discard parts of an Int/String comparison?

Tags: php, string, int, comparison

Was talking to coworkers today about oddities in JavaScript and PHP when I noticed something that, to me, is pretty funky:

```
var_dump( 1 == "123" ); // bool(false)
var_dump( 1 == "1 23" ); // bool(true)
```

The first example is what I would expect. PHP likely coerces the "123" down to an integer and compares them. The second, however, doesn't really make sense. I would think the rules of coercion wouldn't allow the space and the 23 in "1 23" to be discarded to make the comparison, but it seems like PHP just throws them out to do its business.

Am I completely missing something here?

Comment: Using `===` seems to return false.

Comment: It takes to the first non-digit because it was written like that, and [documented as such](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: It boils down to a [simple call to strtol(...,null, 10)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.15/Zend/zend_operators.c#L393), i.e. leading digits are interpreted as a number, everything else is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces aren't valid characters in integers, so the space in your string acts as a terminator when PHP does the string->int conversions

```
$x = "1 23";
$y = "12 3";
$z = "1a 23";
echo (int)$x; // 1
echo (int)$y; // 12
echo (int)$z; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Two answers from comments.

From [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker), the PHP documentation answer:

> It takes to the first non-digit because it was written like that, and [documented as such](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

From [VolkerK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk) we get the RTM answer:

> It boils down to a [simple call to strtol(...,null, 10)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.15/Zend/zend_operators.c#L393), i.e. leading digits are interpreted as a number, everything else is ignored.

And there you have it.

Comment: Hey, wait a second. Mine is not the RTFM answer, but the "If you want to know why: It's in the code"-answer ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK sorry, I can edit that. I considered it RTFM since it's pretty much "the manual" for how PHP works :P